# How can I implement SPAWN command with while loop to provide 'password' multiple times?

Tags: passwords, expect, send, spawn

I'm trying to write a script where based on a given list of hostnames from input.txt file,
I have to copy a file from the source server to the destination server for the user - alex.
Password is same for all hosts.

this asks for password every time and I tried SPAWN command with expect and send.

The **below scripts give password automatically, only for the first prompt**.

I'm aware there are other ways like SSH keys and password-less authentication.

But **my exact requriement here is when I trigger the script - copying.sh  it will ask multiple times for the "password",
in this example 3 times as there are 3 different hosts and I should be able to send it from spawn_file.exp.**

Can some one help me how can I implement it and what changes should I make ?

```
# copying.sh
#------------------------
while read line 
do
    scp /usr/file.txt  alex@${line}://home/temp/
done < input.txt 


#Spawn_file.exp
#------------------------
set timeout -1
spawn sh copying.sh
match_max 100000
expect -exact "Password: "
send -- "abcd1234"
expect eof


#input.txt
#------------------------ 
hostname1
hostname2
hostname3
```

Comment: you must first learn [tag:tcl] to use Expect. you can use my [sexpect](https://github.com/clarkwang/sexpect/) if you are more familiar with shell scripts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

THis is where you use the `exp_continue` command:

```
#Spawn_file.exp
#------------------------
set timeout -1
spawn sh copying.sh
match_max 100000
expect {
    -exact "Password: " {
        send -- "abcd1234"
        exp_continue
    }
    eof
}
```

That `expect` statemennt will wait for *either* "password" or eof.

- If the password prompt is seen, the password will be send, and we'll "loop" in the expect statement
- If `eof` is seen, there is no action, the expect statement ends, and then the expect script ends.